# How can I add an object to data on apollo when sending each request in Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

How can I add an object to data on apollo when sending each request in Nuxt.js? I have an object which is sent on each request and is static too. So, I think there should be something like axios interceptors for apollo but I found nothing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, your answer seems to be for reactjs, I couldn't find the same way in nuxtjs.

Comment: This code is used in my current Nuxt project. Here, it's just vanilla JS, nothing related to React nor Vue.

Comment: I've edited my answer with more context on where to start (for Nuxt). I don't see why I would propose a solution that do not fit the tags without warning you. But as told just above, this is vanillaJS so far and not related to Nuxt. But this solution totally work with Nuxt, hence I use it daily at my job.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this kind of configuration

`/plugins/nuxt-apollo-config.js`

```js
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { from } from 'apollo-link'
import { createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client/core'

export default ({ $config: { baseUrlGraphql } }) => {
  const headersConfig = setContext(() => ({
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'tasty-token',
      'specific-token': 'static_token', // you can put your static data here for example
    },
  }))

  return {
    link: from([
      headersConfig,
      // anotherCustomLink,
      createHttpLink({
        credentials: 'include',
        uri: baseUrlGraphql,
        fetch: (uri, options) => {
          return fetch(uri, options)
        },
      }),
    ]),
  }
}
```

You can then read this documentation to understand how the whole link-thing works: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/

That way, you could add a link in the chain, as in my snippet above (named `anotherCustomLink`) and access/modify the operation down the road

```js
const anotherCustomLink = (operation, forward) => {
  console.log('what is the current context?', operation.getContext())
  operation.setContext(...)
  return forward(operation).map((data) => {
    ...
    return data
  })
}
```

EDIT: as a starting point, you should put this into your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  ...
  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      // recommended: use a file to declare the client configuration (see below for example)
      default: '@/plugins/nuxt-apollo-config.js',
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful for nuxt.js too?

Comment: This kind of configuration was done on my current Nuxt project. There are only small differences between Vue and Nuxt, especially when it's this kind of configuration. But since you posted it with a Nuxt tag, I just answered to Nuxt.

Comment: How it has access to my request data? Is it just working for headers?

Comment: You can configure pretty much anything for your fetcher. As for the request data, you can also have access to it. The documentation is pretty complete for this: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/#managing-context